# CATIA: How to call CATCoPlyExplodeCmd

Tags: c++, catia, caa

Is it possible to call from C++ catia command? How can I get any info about signature for this command?

Thanks,
Danil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible from C++ with the CAA API and environment installed:

```
CATCommand* pCmd = NULL;
hr = ::CATAfrStartCommand("CATCoPlyExplodeCmd", pCmd);
```

I don't know if that command takes any arguments though.